# Como chamar shortcode no wordpress atraves de um select?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

eu tenho uma pagina dentro do meu site em wordpress+woocommerce que tem dois selects, e depois de selecionar os dois, gostaria que em uma DIV abaixo chamasse o produto por shortcode. O problema eh que provavelmente precise de um refresh.

HTML

```
<select class='turno'>
<option value=''>Selecione</option>
<option value='[products skus="a1'>manha</option>
<option value='[products skus="a2'>tarde</option>
<option value='[products skus="a3'>noite</option>   
</select>
<br><br>
<select class='hora'>
<option value=''>Selecione</option>
<option value='[products skus="a1'>1</option>
<option value='[products skus="a2'>2</option>
<option value='[products skus="a3'>3</option>   
</select>
<br><br>
<div><span class="turnoescolhido"></span><span class="horaescolhido"></span>"]</div>
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.turno').on('change', function(){
 $('.turnoescolhido').text($(this).val());
 });

 $('.hora').on('change', function(){
 $('.horaescolhido').text($(this).val());
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer uma atualização parcial do conteúdo da página utlizando AJAX.

De maneira bem simples, você colocaria algo assim na sua página ou arquivo js:

```
$('.hora').on('change', function(){
    var url = 'http://meusite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        dados = {
            "action": "products", // nome do shortcode
            "shortcode": $(this).val() // shortcode completo [products...]
        };

    // carrega valor do shortcode no elemento html
    $('.horaescolhido').load(url, dados);

});
```

E em no seu plugin ou tema:

```
<?php
// essa é a função que é executada quando usuario não está logado
function wp_ajax_nopriv_products_func() {
    wp_ajax_products_func();
}

// essa é executada quando o usuário está logado
function wp_ajax_products_func() {
    $shortcode = isset($_REQUEST['shortcode']) ? $_REQUEST['shortcode'] : '';

    // para do_shortcode() devemos passar o valor completo do shortcode
    // exemplo [products sku="a1"]
    echo do_shortcode($shortcode)

    // esse die é muito importante
    die; 
}

// registra as funções que irão atender a requisição
// o identificador da função deve ser wp_ajax_ + valor_do_action
// e/ou wp_ajax_nopriv_ + valor_do_action
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_products', 'wp_ajax_nopriv_products_func', 1);
add_action('wp_ajax_products', 'wp_ajax_products_func', 1);

?>
```

Algumas referencias:

- [Ajax em plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)
- [Ajax no Wordpress](https://tableless.com.br/requisicoes-ajax-no-wordpress/)